# iframe tag not loading some URL's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am passing some URL's dynamically like http://IP:port/MyProject/dashboard.do?method=loadDashboard.
Some methods of the same action class are not loading which are loading in browser.
here method name like loadDP.
http://IP:port/MyProject/dashboard.do?method=loadDP.

```html
$("#containerId").html(' <ifrme id="iframeId" src= '+ url +' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo issues, it should have to be `iframe` not `ifrme` with missing quotes in `src` attribute:

```
$("#containerId").html('<iframe id="iframeId" src="'+ url +'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>');
//----------------------^^^^^^^^------------------^--here---^
```

Comment: thanks, yeah i changed. $("#container").html('<iframe id="iframeId" src= '+ url +' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>');        but some url's still not loading.